# How bind a ViewModel to a view with with dependency injected service in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

**Background:**

I implemented dependency injection in a WPF application using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.

App.xaml.cs

```
protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    AppHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddTransient<IFileRepository, FileRepository>();
            services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();

        }).Build();

    await AppHost!.StartAsync();
    var startupForm = AppHost.Services.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
    startupForm.Show();

    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

In my OpenProjectViewModel, I inject the fileRepository.

```
public IFileRepository fileRepository { get; }
public OpenProjectViewModel(IFileRepository _fileRepository)
{
    fileRepository = _fileRepository;
}
```

In OpenProjectView.xaml I set the datacontext

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:OpenProjectViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

**The problem**

When that app starts, it doesn't like that I don't have a parameterless constructor in OpenProjectViewModel. When I add a parameterless constructor in OpenProjectViewModel, the app starts but the fileRepository is then empty because it hasn't been injected.

**The question**

Is there a way to let the app know when it should inject the FileRepository when the OpenProjectViewModel is being used? I followed this [guide](https://youtu.be/dLR_D2IJE1M) to set up the DI. But Tim shows you how to set it up in the view code-behind.

Let me know if I missed sharing anything.
Thank you for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't instantiate a viewmodel in XAML unless you're relying on the parameterless constructor.

You should use

```
AppHost.Services.GetRequiredService <MainWindowViewModel>()
```

And set `DataContext` of `MainWindow` in code to the result.

That will then pass `IFileRepository` in as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: I could not get your code to work. but found something like this:

(Application.Current as App).Host.Services.GetRequiredService<MainWindowViewModel>();

But I am guessing "Host" is private so I cant reach it. Any ideas?

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you! In the end I used your suggestion like this: DataContext = App.AppHost?.Services.GetRequiredService<MainWindowViewModel>(); Last thing. Do you know of any good resources you could point me at to read up on stuff like this. Feel Like my googling takes me all over the place. Thanks again!

Comment: For people who stumble across this post. The solution makes it possible to use the view.xaml like a component: <local:OpenProjectView />. If you don't need to use it as a component inject the service into the constructor instead.Like this: 
      public IFileRepository FileRepository { get; }

        public MainWindow(IFileRepository fileRepository)
        {
            FileRepository = fileRepository;
  }